# Dynamically change the type of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to transform an element into another element using JavaScript?

For instance, I have:

```
<p>Début de l'évènement : <time id=event-start></time></p>
<p>Fin de l'évènement : <time id=event-end></time></p>
```

This is a template that is populated through AJAX, however I need to convert the second `time` element to `span` elements in the case that there is no event end time.

The resulting output should be:

```
<p>Début de l'évènement : <time datetime=2014-09-02T08:00:00 id=event-start>2 septembre 2014 à 8h00</time></p>
<p>Fin de l'évènement : <time datetime=2014-09-02T16:00:00 id=event-end>2 septembre 2014 à 16h00</time></p>
```

Or:

```
<p>Début de l'évènement : <time datetime=2014-09-02T08:00:00 id=event-start>2 septembre 2014 à 8h00</time></p>
<p>Fin de l'évènement : <span id=event-end>Indéterminée</span></p>
```

The JavaScript code that I am using to populate the fields:

```
function getEventCallback(data) {
    var startEl = document.getElementById('event-start'),
        endEl = document.getElementById('event-end');

    startEl.textContent = moment(data.start).format( ... );
    startEl.setAttribute('datetime', data.start);

    if (data.end) {
        endEl.textContent = moment(data.end).format( ... );
        endEl.setAttribute('datetime', data.end);
    } else {
        endEl.textContent = 'Indéterminée';
        endEl.removeAttribute('datetime');
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that `endEl` is still a [`HTMLTimeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement) and does not represent some discrete point in time.

I've looked into the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface and it appears that [`Node.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName) is immutable, so how do I go about this?

I can't remove the `time` element completely because subsequent requests might need to use it.

Comment: To create a new node, create a new node.

Comment: Consider... "Out with the old, in with the new."

Comment: I wonder why the duplicate question did not show up in the related questions or while searching. Thanks.

Comment: You say you want to replace the empty `<time>` element with a `<span>`, but "I can't remove the `time` element completely because subsequent requests might need to use it" - how do those two aims fit together?

Comment: @DavidThomas If I remove the `time` element and insert a `span` element, how would the next call insert the data at that location in the document?

Comment: I don't know, yet, because I  haven't thought about it. But given your two contradictory requirements I'm unsure as to quite what it is that you want, or need.